# Acces violation writing location c ,2D dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, computer-science

Dear user im trying to write data into the array but for some reason i get this error all the time.. please help me

```
int** input_array_dyn1(int n,int m) 
{
int i,**a; //index and array we want to set up.
a=(int**)calloc(n,sizeof(int*)); //get room for array in size n of ints.
assert(a); //checking that we have space.
for (i=0;i<n;i++)  //loop for getting value in each cell...
{
a[i]=(int*)calloc(m,sizeof(int)); //get room for array in size n of ints.
assert(a[i]); //checking that we have space.
}
return a; //returning the new array we made.
}

void randomMat(int** a,int n,int m)
 {
int i,j;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)           
    for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
        a[i][j]=rand()%2;

printf ("you'r first matrix is:\n");
//print_mat(a,m,n);
}
```

i always get an error from the line `a[i][j]=rand()%2;` of Acces violation writing location
please help me guys!

Comment: There is no array. Only pointer to pointer. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: 1) Spaces are there for a reason. Format & indent properly 2) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: "I get an error ..." Please be more specific. Syntax error? Segfault? Some guy enters your room and givves you a paper? Oh, and just to make clear: There is still no array.

Comment: Check the difference between `for (i=0;i<n;i++)` and `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)`.

Comment: for readability/understandability by us humans, please consistently indent the code.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level. (never use tabs).  Indent after every opening brace '{'.   un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  separate code blocks (for, if , else, while, do...while, switch, case, defautl) by a blank line.

Comment: When calling calloc() (and family of functions).  In C, the returned type is `void*`, so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: in C, array offsets start with 0 and continue to 'sizeof of array -1'. The posted code skips the first entry in the array and accesses beyond the end of the array upper bound.  The access beyond the end of the upper bound is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the `assert()` function is ok for debugging but is not acceptable for production code as it does not inform the user as to the reason for the code crashing

Comment: for readability and understandability by us humans, please use meaningful names for variables.  in the posted scenario `m` `n` `a` are not really meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

You can see yourself that there is a difference in the loops in `input_array_dyn1` and in `randomMat`

Compare for example

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)  //loop for getting value in each cell...
{
a[i]=(int*)calloc(m,sizeof(int)); //get room for array in size n of ints.
assert(a[i]); //checking that we have space.
}
```

and

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)           
    for(j=1;j<=m;j++)
        a[i][j]=rand()%2;
```

If an array has `n` elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, n-1]`